# Will Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus have LTS?

Tags: lts, release-management, support, 17.04

I've read over the information I can find on 17.04 Zesty Zapus

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes

The only information I can go off of for official support:

"Ubuntu 17.04 will be supported for 9 months until January 2018. If you need Long Term Support, it is recommended you use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS instead."

Does this indicate that 17.x will not at any point have long term support?

Edit:
This was specifically related to *if* 17.04 Zesty Zapus was going to be receiving LTS. *Not* about defining the difference between Non-LTS and LTS. This is meant to be informational to this specifically, not a duplicate of a more broad question.

Comment: 17.04 is not an LTS release, so no LTS support is expected. The next LTS release is supposed to be 18.04, that is, if the current release pattern continues.

Comment: Thank you Mike, that would make sense. If you would like to add that as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Welcome, and happy to oblige.

Comment: Irrespective of what you meant, I don't see the value in having posts about *every* release being an LTS or not, when it can be covered by a single general question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

17.04 is a regular release with 9 months of support, so no LTS support is expected.

Both 14.04 and 16.04 are LTSs, and the next LTS release is supposed to be 18.04, ...that is, if the current release pattern continues.

We've been getting a long term support release every even year in April, 2016.04, 2014.04, 2012.04, 2010.04, etc.

Answer (score 5):

No. LTS edition is released once every 2 year with 5 years support.Next LTS Release will be 18.04.Zesty Zapus is a non LTS release with only 9 months support.